# Chrome extension: Schema "file://" not allowed in "permissions"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest, file-uri

I have a problem with my Chrome extension, exactly with the manifest file.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
     "file://*/*",
     "activeTab",
     "http://www.pdfzorro.com/"
   ],

  "name": "PDFzorro - PDF Editor",
  "version": "0.0.0.11",
  "short_name": "PDF-Dateien bearbeiten - edit PDF files",
  "description": "edit PDF files online, direct from GoogleDrive",
  "icons": { "16": "logo16.png",
          "128": "logo.png" },  

  "container": ["GOOGLE_DRIVE"],
  "api_console_project_id": "000000000000",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }  
}
```

In Dev-Mod the extension works in Chrome. But I cannot upload the zipped extension to the Chrome Web Store.

> Error: Schema "file://" not allowed in "permissions"

I tried also:

```
file:///
file://
file:///*
file://*/*
```

..but nothing works.

The only way the app works und the upload works is to add `<all_urls>` to permissions. But I don't want this in permission because of the warnings when installing the app.

Comment: Interesting. Declaring `"<all_urls>"` in the _optional_ permissions still triggers the warning.

Comment: Nevermind, it's because I already implicitly granted those.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `"<all_urls>"` as an [optional permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) and request the origin at runtime.

Just having it in optional permissions shows the "Allow access to file: URLs" checkbox that user needs to tick anyway.

You can find out the state of that flag, because the origin will be considered invalid unless it's set. So:

```
chrome.permissions.contains(
  {origins: ["file://*"]},
  function(granted){
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      // The flag is not set
      // You need to explain it to the user and then show the page
      // You can open the page scrolled where you need it with the following:
      // chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://extensions?id=" + chrome.runtime.id });
      // Note that just a link won't work
    } else if(!granted) {
      // The flag is set, but the permissions are not yet granted
      // You need to call the next snippet FROM A USER GESTURE (e.g. click)
    } else {
      // Everything is peachy, you have the permissions
    }
  }
);
```

Once that flag is ticked, you can call the following **from a user gesture** to get permissions:

```
chrome.permissions.request(
  {origins: ["file://*"]},
  function(granted) {
    if(!granted) {
      // Should never happen (see below)
    } else {
      // Everything is peachy now
    }
  }
);
```

This will **always succeed** without a dialog to the user as long as the flag is set, but must be called from a user gesture **once**. Permission grants are persisted throughout the installation lifetime.

This will generate no warning at install and CWS *should* make that pass.

Comment: Note that it's not very convenient to the users: they need to read instructions, tick a checkbox in another page that you can't interact with, and then click something again in your UI. But that's the price of non-blanket permissions.

Comment: yes i know :-) i think about it, and i perhaps will set permission all_urls ;-)